# how to send rich text message in system.net.mail

Tags: .net

how to send rich text message in system.net.mail need code for send a mail as html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//create the mail message
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

 //set the addresses
 mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mycompany.com");
 mail.To.Add("you@yourcompany.com");

 //set the content
 mail.Subject = "This is an email";
 mail.Body = "<b>This is bold</b> <font color=#336699>This is blue</font>";
 mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

 //send the message
 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
 smtp.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
mm.Body = "<html>...</html>";
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware, that not every person/mailclient can present a message formatted in HTML. If you rely on layout to make your message clear this can be a problem.